# Excel 2013 VBA programming

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I'll start off my saying I'm trying to save time for a family member who is doing this program manually.

Sheet 1

1. Column A is a start date
2. Column B is a projected start date
3. Column E is a Task Name.

Sheet 2 is a handmade calendar.

1. Tasks are in B8:B17 for Projected start date and B20:B29 for Actual start date
2. Week is C5:AK5, Month is C6:AK6, Day is C7:AK7

What I'm trying to do is:

```
IF cell change in sheet_1(range a2:a999)

Find in sheet 3 (C6:AK7) the location of value entered in sheet 2(active.cell)
    Store column number as Actual_Date_y
Active.Cell
    move active.cell to Location (R,C+4)
    Find in sheet 3 (B20:B29)the String from new active.cell
        Store Row Number as Actual_Date_x

print ("X"), in (Actual_Date_x,Actual_Date_y)
```

I'm a fish out of water when it comes to VBA.

@jcbermu - The project is 35 weeks long (C:AK is 35 columns).
There is a week number (1-35) in row 5 (cells C5:AK5), then he has the month in C6:AK6, lastly he has the calender Sunday date in C7:AK7,
as seen here:
[image: spreadsheet screenshot]

EDIT: @Raystafarian, THANKS, this reads as exactly what I need. I'm going to try it and see what happens.

- @Raystafarian, "not found" every time. I'm going to say it's his format for the dates since there is no continuity between the sheets. I'm going to tweak his sheets and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: I don't understand the data in range C5:AK7. Could you give us an example?

Comment: James: (1) Clarifications to the question *belong* in edits, not comments, so don’t worry.  (Yes, the “Thanks” and subsequent “no thanks” should probably be in comments.)  (2) See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.  Then you can edit your own question without going through peer review.  (3) Nice gravatar.

Answer (score 0):

Literally, what you want translates to something like this in the worksheet module for sheet 1 -

```
Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)

Dim actdatex As Integer
Dim actdatey As Integer
Dim newcell As Range
Dim rngdate As Range



If Not Intersect(target, Range("A2:A999")) Is Nothing Then
On Error GoTo handler
 For Each c In Range("Sheet3!C6:AK7")
    If c = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(target.Address) Then
     actdatex = c.Column
     Exit For
    End If
 Next

 Set newcell = Range(target).Offset(, 4)

 For Each d In Range("Sheet3!B20:B29")
    If d = newcell Then
        actdatey = d.Row
    Exit For
    End If
 Next

 Set rngdate = Cells(actdatex, actdatey)
 rngdate = "X"

End If


handler:
MsgBox ("not found")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim wks1 As Worksheet
Dim cell1, cell2, myrange As Range
Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
Set wks = wkb.Sheets(1)
Set wks1 = wkb.Sheets(2)
targetrow = Target.Row
targetcolumn = Target.Column
task = wks.Cells(targetrow, 3)
For i = 3 To 300
    a = wks1.Cells(6, i)
    If a = "" Then
        i = 301
    End If
    If a = Target.Value Then
        initialrow = 20
        If targetcolumn = 2 Then
            initialrow = initialrow - 12
        End If
        realrow = initialrow + targetrow - 2
        For j = 3 To 300
            wks1.Cells(realrow, j) = ""
            If wks1.Cells(6, j) = "" Then
                j = 301
            End If
        Next j
        wks1.Cells(realrow, i) = "X"
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

It works only under some conditions:

1. On *Sheet1* the columns must be in this order: `Start Date | Projected Date | Task Name`.
2. On *Sheet2* the `month` and `Sunday date` **must** be the same.

   I will give you an example: On cell `C6` and cell `c7` you put 01/03/2015 and using cell format you select *custom* and use `mmm` on c6 and `dd`on C7.
3. The order of tasks **must** be the same on *Sheet1* and *Sheet2*.
4. On *Sheet2* the first task must be on cells `B8` and `B20`.

The VBA code must be put on **Sheet 1**. You need to open Macros and on the left column, double click the worksheet, and then paste the code on the right side. Whenever a date changes on `Sheet1` it is updated on `Sheet2`.